# What is the usage of defining many elements types in list type as for tuple type?

Tags: python, list, type-hinting

Since *Python 3.9*, there are type hints built-in and for a `list` type, there's a possibility to define also type of its elements.

When all the list's elements have the same type, it's simple: `list[str]`.
When the elements' types are different, we can define a type hint like:

- `list[Union[str, int]]` (using `typing` library to import `Union`),
- `list[str | int]` (since *Python 3.11* and *PEP 604*).

However, with the built-in type hits, there's a **possibility** to write `list` type like this:

```py
list[str, int]
```

But it seems not to be intended to work like in `tuple` type case: `tuple[str, int]` - the first tuple element is a string, and the second is an integer.
Why? In addition to being able to use a correct notation like in the examples listed above, I found two more arguments against the `list[str, int]`:

- `typing.List[str, int]` isn't provided and throws an error `TypeError: Too many arguments for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1`,
- a type expected for every element of such a list is the first defined type (here: `str`) as IDEs (in my case: *PyCharm*) inform about:

  ```py
  def get_second_element(str_int_list: list[str, int]) -> int:
      return str_int_list[1]  # Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead


  print(get_second_element(["string", 1])
  ```

To sum up, the factors described above leads me to assume the notation with a comma (`,`) isn't correct.
But still, there's a possibility to use it. Why? What's the usage?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use that syntax. No typechecker will recognize `list[int, str]` as anything more than nonsense. The only reason the Python runtime allows it at *all* is efficiency. The Python development team has noted many times that `typing` is an incredibly bloated module and that loading all of the metaclass magic that allows syntax like `List[int]` to *work* puts a lot of strain on the Python runtime.

The same would be true of `list` and `tuple` and all of those types if they were each special-cased, and since those types are built-in, we would pay the runtime cost of type annotations every time we started up a Python interpreter. So rather than force everyone to pay that cost, [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) (the proposal that allowed `list` and other types to be subscripted directly) kept it incredibly simple. Rather than defining a bunch of runtime semantics for all of these types, it made them all work in a very uniform way. Built-in types (including, but not limited to, `list` and `tuple`) take one or more arguments in brackets. This subscript operation constructs a [`GenericAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.GenericAlias) object that can be inspected at runtime.

Typecheckers are free to add common sense restrictions to this. Mypy definitely throws a fit if I pass more than one argument to `list[...]`, and rightly so. `tuple[...]`, on the other hand, is designed to take variable arguments, so `tuple[str, int]` actually makes sense (and, as you've already noted, indicates a 2-tuple whose first element is a string and whose second is an integer). But the Python runtime doesn't care about any of this; it simply does the bare minimum work necessary to allow the bracketing syntax to work and produce a valid Python object.